# Google Cloud Speech-to-Text Automatic Punctuation

Tags: google-speech-api, punctuation, google-speech-to-text-api, transcription

I've retrieved transcriptions using the python code provided by the GCSTT documentation for getting transcriptions with automatic punctuation (https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/automatic-punctuation). However, I realized I never specified the model to use, as it wasn't included in the provided code's parameters for RecognitionConfig().

I'd like to know, which model is being used by default?

I've gone through the documentation, but I can't find anything.